# select records with a 6 month interval

Tags: sql, oracle, date, intervals, date-arithmetic

I want to select with an oracle sql statement the records with a 6 month time interval.

Example

```
01/06/2011  AMOUNT
01/12/2011  AMOUNT 
01/06/2012 AMOUNT
01/12/2012 AMOUNT
```

And so on

How can I do this with oracle sql?

Answer (score 2):

```
select ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate), (rownum - 1) * 6) some_date
  from dual
connect by level <= 5;

SOME_DATE
-----------
18.04.2014
18.10.2014
18.04.2015
18.10.2015
18.04.2016
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH     got_r_num     AS
(
     SELECT     t.*     -- OR WHATEVER YOU WANT
     ,     DENSE_RANK () OVER ( PARTITION BY TRUNC (created_date, 'MONTH')
                         ORDER BY       TRUNC (created_date)     -- DESC
                       )     AS r_num
     FROM     test_table
     WHERE     MOD ( MONTHS_BETWEEN ( TRUNC (SYSDATE)
                         , TRUNC (created_date)
                         )
              , 6
              ) = 0
)
SELECT     *     -- or list all columns except r_num
FROM     got_r_num
WHERE     r_num     = 1
;
```

Have a look [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/993724?start=0&tstart=0) please .

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sum of all records of 6 months in the `AMOUNT` field:
You can subquery with sum function and query with `CONNECT BY LEVEL`

```
SELECT x AS l_date, 
(
SELECT sum(your_data)
FROM your_table
WHERE table_date >= x
 AND table_date   < add_months(x,6)
)AMOUNT
FROM(
     SELECT add_months(to_date('01/06/2011','dd/mm/yyyy'),(LEVEL-1)*6) x
     FROM dual
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4
);
```